# Hive results differs from MySql result. Join query on Hive returns unexpected result or OK results

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have a join query (that joins 4 table) on mysql returns 2 rows while on Hive returns OK results. So I checked table individually on hive and mysql side.

Records on each table on both side matches but the results with JOIN query differs. It is not the case for the other JOIN query.

I have checked the directory for all the tables which look fine.

The OK results comes specially when there is no records on either of table or no directory available for table. But that is not the case.

Is the OK results on hive an issue.

Below is the part of the result:

```
Stage-Stage-6: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 22.22 sec   MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-7: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 24.94 sec   MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Stage-Stage-8: Map: 2  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 22.25 sec   MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 minutes 36 seconds 110 msec
OK
Time taken: 411.225 seconds
hive>
```

Comment: Imaging you are one of us who have no idea about your app other than what you tell us! ___Now try and give an answer to the question you have written___

Comment: thanks for the review but what seems to be not understandable? I have updated the question. Please respond if you could. @RiggsFolly

Comment: it is the question to hive expert. If it doesn't make sense that's fine for me @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Based on the reported behavior, we can deduce that there is a *difference* between what's implemented on MySQL, and what's implemented on Apache Hive.

As far as whether the difference is due to a difference in the JOIN behavior, there's not enough information given here to determine why the query against MySQL and the query against Hive would be returning different results.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please let me know if you would like to review query. It's a simple join and left join query that joins 4 tables. I usually build a query on mysql and after it runs and returns the results as expected I modify it to run on Hive.  I don't have any issue with other similar quires that I have been running. But for this one I have issue. @spencer7593